# Add/Remove classes and using Cookie to remember selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simply piece of JQuery that toggle a class on anchor tags/links.
What I don't know is how do I make the class toggle or add/remove when the other links are clicked? Example: The class can only apply to the link that is click and cannot be on more than one at a time. That's where I am stuck. Well, I don't know how to do it.

Secondly how do I use the JQuery Cookie to keep the currently link active. I have downloaded the cookie extension.

Here is what I have done:

HTML:

```
<ul class="navbar">
 <li><a  href="#/">Link1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/">Link2</a></li>
 <li><a  href="#/">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.activeLink{
    color: #930;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.navbar li a').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('activeLink');
}); 
});
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a solution that uses event propagation:

```
$(function() {

    var $activeLink,
        activeLinkHref = $.cookie('activeLinkHref'),
        activeClass = 'activeLink';

    $('.navbar').on('click', 'a', function() {
        $activeLink && $activeLink.removeClass(activeClass);
        $activeLink = $(this).addClass(activeClass);
        $.cookie('activeLinkHref', $activeLink.attr('href'));
    });

    // If a cookie is found, activate the related link.
    if (activeLinkHref) 
    $('.navbar a[href="' + activeLinkHref + '"]').click();

});​
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TGeZ2/) (without the cookie functionality as JSFiddle lacks support).

Comment: Let me quickly play around with this and let you know. I would have never came up with such and answer.

Comment: Thanks Depot for all your help, you guys makes such a great big difference!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it. It's a little simplistic, but it gets the job done without a lot of brain strain.

```
<ul class="navbar">
 <li><a  href="#/">Link1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/">Link2</a></li>
 <li><a  href="#/">Link3</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.navbar li a').click(function(){
    $('.navbar li a').css('color', 'black');
    $(this).css('color', '#930');
}); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where is cookies usage? it is not coplete answer.

Comment: And I flagged your post as it is rude and unconstructive as we are helping him with a part of his problem. Perhaps you should try to answer the question instead of trying to downvote the people who are trying to help even if it isn't with all of the problem.

Comment: @TabethaMoe +1 For at least a partial answer.