# Remembering last selected href/button through a cookie with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I have a document that uses 4 links on the top navigation. Upon clicking the link a div right below it changes size. What I want to accomplish is to use a cookie to remember the last selected link.

Here is the code for the links:

```
<li><a href="#" class="desktop">Desktop</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="tablet">Tablet</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="tabletP">Tablet (P)</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="mobile">Mobile</a></li>
```

And after that I have the jQuery Code that controls the DIV.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".desktop").click(function() {
        $(".iframe").animate({"width" : "100%"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
        $(".iframe").animate({"height" : "100%"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
    });
    $(".tablet").click(function() {
        $(".iframe").animate({"width" : "1040px"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
        $(".iframe").animate({"height" : "488px"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
    });
    $(".tabletP").click(function() {
        $(".iframe").animate({"width" : "788px"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
        $(".iframe").animate({"height" : "488px"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
    });
    $(".mobile").click(function() {
        $(".iframe").animate({"width" : "350px"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
        $(".iframe").animate({"height" : "488px"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
    });
});
```

For now I am using the [jQuery Cookie Pluging](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) from which I have created the following code to create the cookie. I tweaked the above jQuery code to look like this:

```
$(".desktop").click(function() {
    $(".iframe").animate({"width" : "100%"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
        $(".iframe").animate({"height" : "100%"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
        $.cookie("lastState", "desktop", { expires: 7 });
});
$(".tablet").click(function() {
    $(".iframe").animate({"width" : "1040px"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
    $(".iframe").animate({"height" : "488px"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
    $.cookie("lastState", "tablet", { expires: 7 });
});
$(".tabletP").click(function() {
    $(".iframe").animate({"width" : "788px"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
    $(".iframe").animate({"height" : "488px"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
    $.cookie("lastState", "tabletP", { expires: 7 });
});
$(".mobile").click(function() {
        $(".iframe").animate({"width" : "350px"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
        $(".iframe").animate({"height" : "488px"},{queue: false, duration: 1000 });
    $.cookie("lastState", "mobile", { expires: 7 });
});
```

Now I need to know how to read the cookie created and give out the necessary output, which is to auto select the link which would change the size of the above mentioned div.

I had a look at some other questions. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820544/add-remove-classes-and-using-cookie-to-remember-selection) seemed to very close to what I was looking for. But the code suggested in that question is a little confusing

Below is the code from that question:

```
$(function() {

    var $activeLink,
        activeLinkHref = $.cookie('activeLinkHref'),
        activeClass = 'activeLink';

    $('.navbar').on('click', 'a', function() {
        $activeLink && $activeLink.removeClass(activeClass);
        $activeLink = $(this).addClass(activeClass);
        $.cookie('activeLinkHref', $activeLink.attr('href'));
    });

    // If a cookie is found, activate the related link.
    if (activeLinkHref) 
    $('.navbar a[href="' + activeLinkHref + '"]').click();

});​
```

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: `var linkClicked = $.cookie('lastState'); if(linkClicked){ $('a.'+ linkClicked +'').click(); }`? Did you try to change that code to do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted shows you how to get the value from the cookie, this is the line that sets a gets the value from the cookie:

`cookieVal= $.cookie('lastState')`

And this is the line to check to see if anything was found:

`if (cookieVal)`

So given that, you know how to get the value from the cookie, and also how to check to see if the value was found. If you found a value, then go onto the next step, which is to select the specific link using the value you got from the cookie.

You're storing the class of the element in the cookie, so you can use that in your selector for your simulated click event ex:

`$('.' + cookieVal).click();`